# How to use margins and paddings with Java GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

How can I keep a JLabel from displaying flush against the side of the frame? I have the same problem when using GridLayout or BoxLayout.

Here's an example where this happens:

```
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
content.add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
```

CSS has the concept of margins and padding. Does Java have similar?

I still want Left justified but with a few pixels of space between the edge and the label.

Comment: You mean, you want it centered?

Comment: You just had luck, I looked back to this question, next time, write a comment to my answer, i should see your edit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could set an empty border for the `JLabel` to move the component over a few pixels from the left edge:

```
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

For centered labels, try this:

```
content.add(new JLabel("Hello World", JLabel.CENTER));
```

If you're using `Box`, you can add space by calling,(on a vertical box):

```
content.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(height));
content.add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
```

Or for horizontal:

```
content.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(width));
```