# How to create a border with a line and padding for a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a JPanel that has a line border as well as margin (padding), like this

[image]

but I want to do it without the need to nest JPanel with different borders as currently

```
public class FolderSelect extends JPanel {

    public FolderSelect() {
        super() ;
        BorderLayout bl =new BorderLayout(10,10) ;
        JPanel margin = new JPanel(bl) ;

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

        margin.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        margin.add(new JLabel("Folder to check..."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START) ;
        margin.add(new JTextField("path/to/folder/to/scan"), BorderLayout.CENTER) ;
        margin.add(new JButton("..."), BorderLayout.LINE_END) ;
        this.add(margin) ;
    }
}
```

Can I set a line border with top, right, bottom and left padding in a single JPanel ?

I actually want to achieve this with JPanel borders without nesting them [image]

I do not wish to paint my custom border, I want to know if SWT allows this without nesting panels

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use nested components, it's frankly the easiest solution, and if you need to do it multiple times just create a custom JPanel that adds the borders, and override the `add(Component)` method so that it behaves like a JPanel without another nested panel.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want to nest, then consider adding padding individual components instead, and paint the border by overriding the paintComponent method or with a custom border with insets that you desire. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547361/how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-with-java-gridlayout Or use another appropriate layout manager, or use absolute component positioning and sizing for as much control as you need (with a resize method if the JPanel gets resized).

Comment: @sorifiend - to answer your first comment it just seems like a waste of resources to nest three panels just to achieve what is very common now days with the HTML CSS boxing model, specially when I'm planning on creating multiple of those in my JFrame - I have actually just created a custom panel that hides those implementation details but still feels wrong

Comment: Yeah, it isn't great, swing development stopped and fell behind a long time ago. I would encourage you to look into JavaFX for your next Java UI project, it has a lot more support for things like this and a more modern design approach, although granted Swing is still very powerful and can do pretty much anything with enough time and effort to write custom code.

Comment: That is a great suggestion since I was just getting started creating UI components, so I could switch without too much effort. If you provide your comments as answer I would like to grant you the credits for it. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at CompoundBorder. It was created exactly for your usecase. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri comment is actually what I'm looking for, creating a custom border is more complex than what I need and that answer that Hiran mentions is not provided in the other question, so this might be usefull. Please provide it as answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is a simple combination of borders for one component. This is what [CompoundBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) was created for.